# Laravel - How to validate Form Request before executing middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I have a question on Form Request validations and middlewares-

I'm wondering how can I make my requests go through my custom Form Request validation before entering my middleware stack.

Long story short... I have some API endpoints, some middlewares to perform some logic validation and a Form Request class in which I validate that the input parameters are syntactically correct using some regular expressions.

My problem is that I would like the request to first go through the Form Request validation and then (when I know that all parameter meet their syntax requirements) go through the middleware stack.

I know I could try to match the input parameters in the middleware and return an error but then I would have duplicated the validation logic and I don´t want that.

I have tried to type-hint the FormRequest class in the middleware´s handle method but then it gives me an error saying that I should pass a FormRequest instance and I passed a Request instance.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can use plain javascript or jquery to do it

Comment: I think your best option is to create new middleware, register it as first and call the validation from there. If your current validation is inside the controller you might want to refractor your code to make it usable from the middleware.

Comment: I think your issue is performing logic validation inside of the middleware.  Is there some way you can create some abstract base form request class instead and move the logic to there?  Then you'd have your form request classes all extending the base one?

Comment: @ThomasMoors I don't perform any validation inside the controller. I just type-hint the Form Request class and assume that all input parameters are valid. I could do the validation in the middleware but then I would be duplicating the validation code (once in the middleware and once in the form request class). By the way, the middleware is only called in some of the endpoints but the Form Request validations affect all controller methods. If I could call the Form Request class from the middleware handle method that would solve my problem but I couldn't figure how to do it.

Comment: @user3158900 Maybe it's a missconception I have on the use of middlewares but I'm using them (among other things) to make sure the controller methods only do the work they are supposed to do and not validation or database updates, stats, etc... Besides that, the middleware I'm talking about is only executed on a few endpoints while the Form Request validations are executed on all endpoints. I've managed to create a Form Request class that works on all my endpoints since validations are similar. To refactor that I would have to create a Form Request class per endpoint.

Comment: For anyone reading this and wondering what did I ended up doing: I checked that the Form Request class didn´t even got constructed by the time the middleware handle function was being called so I just did the parameters syntax checking in the middleware.